# Help removing Pressure Balance valve

Tags: shower, pressure

I need some assistance. I’m replacing a American Standard Pressure balance valve from shower/tub handle. I removed all the parts to valve but the valve is stuck in there and won’t come
Out.
I used pliers, flathead screwdriver, twisted and pulled but it won’t come out. I’m worried about breaking it in there. Are there any tips or
Tricks to remove it?

Comment: we cannot see what you are looking at

Answer (score 2):

After removing all the screws you can clearly see you need a special tool to pull it out. It might resist a bit so be patient. Some screws are small so to prevent them falling in the drain cover it with a towel. Take pictures of each step so to know how to assemble it.

You can also use a simple paint can opener to pull it out.

Here is a video explaining it in details.

https://youtu.be/hhBanjCN5n4